# h2o.grid in R - Accessing processing time for each iteration

Tags: r, h2o, grid-search

Is there any way to extract the time/memory required for each iteration of a grid search? I am looking to plot an outcome metric (e.g. AUC) vs. processing requirements to examine the cost-benefit of adding complexity to my model.

Comment: **1.** There's no reason that one iteration would have the same requirements as any other iteration. They almost never would, because every iteration has a different set of hyperparameters, like the number of trees, learning rate, etc. **2.** No, you can't know before doing it. You can only record how long it took you to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "each iteration of the grid search", you mean each model in the grid search.  So you're asking how to find model training times in a grid search.  If so, here's how to do that.

H2O stores the model start time in the model (as milliseconds since unix epoch time).  You can use that to determine the time between models -- this can be used to deduce the training time for any model (except the last one).

In R, the model start time is stored at `my_model@model$start_time`.
Here is an example using the iris dataset and a GBM grid:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

# Load iris dataset 
data("iris")
train <- as.h2o(iris)


# GBM hyperparamters 
gbm_params <- list(learn_rate = seq(0.01, 0.1, 0.01),
                    max_depth = seq(2, 10, 1),
                    sample_rate = seq(0.5, 1.0, 0.1),
                    col_sample_rate = seq(0.1, 1.0, 0.1)) 
search_criteria <- list(strategy = "RandomDiscrete", max_models = 5)

# Train and cross-validate a grid of GBMs 
gbm_grid <- h2o.grid("gbm", x = 1:4, y = 5,
                      training_frame = train,
                      nfolds = 3,
                      ntrees = 100,
                      seed = 1,
                      hyper_params = gbm_params,
                      search_criteria = search_criteria)

# Model Start times (milliseconds since unix epoch) 
start_times <- sort(sapply(gbm_grid@model_ids, function(m) h2o.getModel(m)@model$start_time))

# Model training times (milliseconds) 
train_time_ms <- start_times[2:length(start_times)] - start_times[1:(length(start_times)-1)] 
print(train_time_ms)
# 758 662 532 469
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, Erin; I apologize for the poor word choice. Thanks!

Comment: If you found my answer useful, can you please give it an upvote?

Comment: I have. But due to my newness to StackOverflow (rep. < 15), it is not displayed.

Comment: No worries.  Welcome to Stack Overflow! :-)